# UITableView content not appear in UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, popup, uitableview, uialertview

I put a custom UITableViewController into a UIAlertView. I populated the table, but content not appear.

```
- (void)addC { // <== This is get called first
    //Create alertView
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    //PopUpTableViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController
    PopUpTableViewController *popUpViewController = [[PopUpTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    // ..
    popUpViewController.array = ...;
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 8, 300, MIN(8*44, categoricalVariables.count*44)) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    popUpViewController.tableView = tableView;
    tableView.delegate = popUpViewController;
    tableView.dataSource = popUpViewController;
    popUpViewController.tableView.tag = 1;

    [alertView addSubview:popUpViewController.tableView];

   //Show alertView
    [alertView show];
}

- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView { 
// This method is an UIAlertViewDelegate method.
// I set here the sizes of alertView and tableView
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)[alertView viewWithTag:1];
    CGRect r0 = tableView.frame;
    r0.size.width = alertView.frame.size.width - 20;
    tableView.frame = r0;

    CGRect r = alertView.frame;
    r.size.height = tableView.frame.size.height + 24;
    alertView.frame = r;     
}
```

Comment: have you tried to set the message of the alertview to something like @"\n\n\n\n"? I rember a project where this helped me out

Comment: I've tried just now, nothing, table is still empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much better approach to use UIActionSheet that to nest a UITableView into an UIAlertView.

Answer (score 0):

Try reload the tableview in willPresentAlertView
By the way, if PopUpTableViewController is subclass of UITableViewController, I think there is no need to set the tableview and its delegate and datasource again. Since all these will be automatically set when you alloc and init.